# Jenkins Docker Build: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb

Tags: .net, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build **dotnet 8** docker image through a **jenkins pipeline**.
But I'm getting the below error:

```
#6 3.287 Reading package lists...
#6 4.462 E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
#6 4.462 E: Sub-process returned an error code
#6 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update       && apt-get install -y psmisc dos2unix p7zip-full       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
------
 > [ 2/14] RUN apt-get update       && apt-get install -y psmisc dos2unix p7zip-full       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
1.072 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
1.108 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
1.109 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
1.303 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8787 kB]
1.747 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]
1.748 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [134 kB]

4.462 E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
4.462 E: Sub-process returned an error code
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update       && apt-get install -y psmisc dos2unix p7zip-full       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
```

I'm able to build the image locally in my machine, but failing in jenkins pipeline.

`docker Version: 24.0.7`

here is my DockerFile used to build:

```
ARG DOTNET_BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk
ARG DOTNET_VERSION=8.0.100-1-bookworm-slim
ARG LIB_JPEG=libjpeg62
# for .NET 3 (debian):
#ARG DOTNET_BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk
#ARG DOTNET_VERSION=3.1
#ARG LIB_JPEG=libjpeg62-turbo
FROM ${DOTNET_BASE_IMAGE}:${DOTNET_VERSION}

# install tools needed in pipeline
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y psmisc dos2unix p7zip-full \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install packages required for tm5 test execution
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y libgdiplus ${LIB_JPEG} \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install sonarqube dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jre \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install required powershell modules
RUN pwsh -Command "Install-Module -Name Pester -RequiredVersion 5.5.0 -Scope AllUsers -Force" \
      && pwsh -Command "Install-Module -Name PSScriptAnalyzer -RequiredVersion 1.21.0 -Scope AllUsers -Force" \
      && pwsh -Command "Install-Module -Name SqlServer -RequiredVersion 22.1.1 -Scope AllUsers -Force" \
      && pwsh -Command "Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore -RequiredVersion 4.1.484 -Scope AllUsers -Force"

# provide module to convert PSScriptAnalyzer output to XML
COPY /pwsh_modules /pwsh_modules
```

Comment: I have tried using **8.0.101-jammy** but still it is giving the same error